# Can a server send to client both session token and session id?

Tags: session, session-variables

**Background:**

I am performing some tests on an application which has a login feature. Client logs-in in the server, server sends it an authentication token and a user id. Client uses token and user id in next requests to authenticate itself.

I'm not much familiar with how such login sessions work. I'm confused about 1 thing that I need to confirm.

**Question:**

The way app is working is that both token and user id are sent in HTTP requests to retrieve sensitive data from server, but in some requests just user id is sent to retrieve sensitive data.

The confusion is, server needs to know that it is talking to an authenticated client. Servers usually verify it with session id or session token. When my client app is sending just "user id" then why is server responding to it,  and giving it sensitive data...

In some apps, I have seen that both session id and user id have same value(separate entities but with same values), so probably in my app "user id" represents "session id". But why would server send both session token and session id...So, my question is

***Can servers send both session token and session id, or they must(or mostly) send just one of them?***

My main question is above one, following is a secondary question:

***Are "session ids" and "user ids" usually same or different? If these are different, then is user id some session variable or something unrelated to session such as id of user in server DB?***

**P.S.:** I'm not sure if it is the right site for this question. Let me know if it needs to be moved to some other stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer the question asked:**

You may be confused about the role a session id plays. Session IDs and tokens are the same thing.  A session id/token allows the server to perform some sort of look up which will indicate "requests with this session token are being performed by this user".  So you don't need to send both the user id and the session token.

**A little more information that you may not have asked for:**

Session tokens do have some security concerns around them.  They must be reasonably unique and should only be communicated over https.  Also, remember that it is easy for a client to modify their cookies.  So if a user id and a session token are sent, if the application blindly accepts the user id token then it may be possible for a user to log in, obtain a session token, and then change their user ID to some unfortunate user they wish to impersonate.

Now, perhaps you're thinking about authentication tokens?  Session tokens can be thought of as a subset of authentications.  They are predicated upon the server have a secret the client does not have access to.  There's a few ways to do that, either create a reasonably unique value and store it with some extra information or perform some encryption of a value which only the server can decrypt.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I need to clarify somethings. So, I understand that session token/id and user id are two different things, and tokens help server identify the user, which can also be achieved by "user id".  So, server does not need to send both token and user id, but in my case it is sending both of them.  The token here is auth token. Client sends auth token in requests to authenticate itself. Token is what tell server that request is part of active login session and it should be responded to. Then why should server respond to a request that is coming only with userid?

Comment: Is this a right/secure implementation by developers to accept requests that contain only userid and no auth token? How would server know that this HTTP request is part of an active login session? Is userid considered an authentication indicator itself? Note that in my case, requests with userid are accepted even when user has logged out...

Comment: This is really specific to the application and if "user id" is secure enough to reasonably validate that the user is who they say they are, then things should be fine.  However that is really implementation dependent.  For instance if a user id is simply the hashed id, is it hashed with SHA and a salt or is it hased with a vulnerable algorithm, like MD5.  It sounds like you may have a potential bug on your hands and should reasonably raise the flag to get some attention, at the very least for your own piece of mind.